# How to fix Javascript multiplication onchange

Tags: javascript, html, multiplication

I'm not sure why my code isn't multiplying the two numbers when I change them. Once I enter a number in the Multiplier field, the onchange function continues adding values and if its a null value, it enters "NaN"

```
<body> 
<h1>Mutiply</h1>
<p>Multiplicand: <input type="text" id="multiplicand" value="0" onchange="multiply()"></p>
<p>Multiplier: <input type="text"/ id="multiplier" value="0" onchange="multiply()"></p> <br>
<div> 
    <p><span id="showMulipicand">0</span>
     × 
    <span id="showMultiplier">0</span> = <span id="showProduct">0</span></p> 
</div> 
<script src="multiply.js"></script> 


multiply() { 
  var multiplicand = document.getElementById('multiplicand').value; 
  var multiplier = document.getElementById('multiplier').value; 
  var showProduct = parseInt(multiplicand) * parseInt(multiplier); 
  var p = document.getElementById('showProduct'); 
  p.innerHTML += showProduct; 
}
```

Comment: just remove the `+` from `p.innerHTML +=`

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the result to the content of your `p` tag.

If you just want to show the result, you have to override the innerHTML instead of appending to it.

```
p.innerHTML = showProduct;
```

Also, if you want to update the result as you type, use the `oninput` event instead of `onchange` which will only trigger when you leave the `<input>` field.

If you also want to update the multiplier and multiplicand fields, just do the same as for the product:

```
document.getElementById('showMulipicand').innerHTML = multiplicand;
```

To avoid `NaN` problems, when you read the multiplier/multiplicand from the `<input>`, do a logical `or` with 0, this way, if the field is blank, its value will be 0.

You should also change the `<input>` type from `text` to `number`.

Here is the code for showing the multiplication result:

```js
function multiply() { 
  const multiplicand = document.getElementById('multiplicand').value || 0; 
  const multiplier = document.getElementById('multiplier').value || 0; 
  const product = parseInt(multiplicand) * parseInt(multiplier);
  document.getElementById('showMulipicand').innerHTML = multiplicand; 
  document.getElementById('showMultiplier').innerHTML = multiplier; 
  document.getElementById('showProduct').innerHTML = product; 
}
```

```html
<h1>Mutiply</h1>
<p>Multiplicand: <input type="number" id="multiplicand" value="0" oninput="multiply()"></p>
<p>Multiplier: <input type="number" id="multiplier" value="0" oninput="multiply()"></p>
<p>
    <span id="showMulipicand">0</span> × 
    <span id="showMultiplier">0</span> = <span id="showProduct">0</span>
</p>
```

Comment: How do I do that? @jo_va

Comment: I'm suppose to have a number in the Multiplicand field (6) and a number in the Multiplier field (2) and where the 0x0=0 it's suppose to return 6x2=12 onchange as I type the multiplier(2) field @jo_va

Comment: It is now working for the multiplicand and multiplier fields too